# Android WebView Content is Not Justified

Tags: android, android-webview, text-justify

```
I read all possible questions/response on stackoverflow, but i still can't do what i would like.

I created an application to show News
    1. Used**Thoolika.ttf** Unicode font. 
    2.Now I am using **AnjaliOldLipi.ttf** font
    3.Older data was in the form **c&not;&yen;Vvp&cent;: d&iexcl;...**.
    4.New data is in the form **&#3384 ; &#3394 ; &#3370 ; &#3405 ; &#3370 ;** .
```

My problem is I can't justify this news inside a webview.For this,I am using html given below.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html; charset=UTF-8 />
    <meta name=viewport content=width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=5.0; user-scalable   = yes /><style>@font-face { font-family: 'Anjali';src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/**AnjaliOldLipi.ttf'**);}body { font-family: 'Anjali';}</style></head><body style=font-family:Anjali;margin:5px;><div style=padding:5px;**text-align:justify;** >
    <span style=color:#3070AC;font-family:Anjali;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;>NEWS TITLE</span><br>
    <div style=width:100%;text-align:right;padding-top:2px;padding-right:2px;color:#BCBCBC;font-family:monospace;font-size:11px;><i>NEWS DATE</i></div></div>
    <div style=padding-top:5px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;color:#000000;font-family:Anjali;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;text-align:;>
    NEWS CONTENT
    </div></body></html>
```

How can i align both left and right side of this webview(**justify**).